# List of administrators

Tags: discord.js

I am trying to make the bot to show all the members that has the administrator permission through a field.

Edit: I haven't upload all the code so I edited it, I am sorry!

```
command(client, 'serverinfo', message => {
   const { guild } = message
  
   const { name, region, memberCount, owner, } = guild
   const icon =guild.iconURL()
   const member = message.member;
   const Administrators = member.hasPermission("ADMINISTRATORS")


   const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()

       .addFields(
     {
      name: 'Server Owner',
      value: owner.user.tag,
      inline: true,
     },
     {
      name: 'Members in server',
      value: memberCount,
      inline: true,
     },
     {
      name: 'Region',
      value: region,
      inline: true,
     },
     {
       name: 'Administrators',
       value: (`Currently all administrators are: ${Administrators.user}`)
     },
   )
   message.channel.send(embed)
 })
```

Comment: @isherwood Hey! I wanted to make it to show all administrators but someone already helped! Thank you for answering anyways :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`GuildMember.hasPermission()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMember?scrollTo=hasPermission) returns a boolean of whether the given member has the given permission, not an array of `GuildMembers`.

If you want an array (or collection in this case), you must [`filter()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/collection/master/class/Collection?scrollTo=filter) the [`GuildMemberManager.cache`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMemberManager?scrollTo=cache) collection, and then [`map()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/collection/master/class/Collection?scrollTo=map) it.

```js
const administrators = message.guild.members.cache.filter((member) =>
 member.hasPermission('ADMINISTRATOR')
);

console.log(
 `Administrators:\n${administrators.map(({ id }) => `<@${id}>`).join('\n')}`
);
```